# PHP - output object keys only

Tags: php, json

How to **output object keys only**, without values?

**Simple Example**: `json_encode()` on **object** returns this:

```
{
    "main": 
    {
        "menu": "something"
    }
}
```

I want to receive this:

```
{
    "main": 
    [
        "menu"
    ]
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this function

```
function recursive_keys($arr)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $result[$key] = recursive_keys($value,$result);
            continue;
        }

        $result[] = $key;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**use:**

```
$array = array(
    "key" => array(
        "Subkey1" => "value1",
        "Subkey2" => "value2"
    ),
    "key2" => array(
        "subKey3"=> array(
            "subKey4"=>"value3"
            )
        )
);

print_r(recursive_keys($array));
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [key] => Array
        (
            [0] => Subkey1
            [1] => Subkey2
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [subKey3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => subKey4
                )

        )

)
```

I'm sure there's a better implementation using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) but, it works

**edit**
 this is the result with json_encode

```
{
  "key": [
    "Subkey1",
    "Subkey2"
  ],
  "key2": {
    "subKey3": [
      "subKey4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object's values are just string or number (not another array or object) then you can just cast the object as array and then you can easily get the keys by array_keys() function and encode it as follows:

```
$array = (array)($object);
$keys = json_encode(array_keys($array));
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit? Code-only answers, while possibly correct, don't help others understand the process that led you to write the answer, and could lead others to just copy/paste your code without knowing what it does.